# Android Studio GridLayout Compatibility for older Androids

Tags: android, compatibility

I'm getting this error when trying to emulate my app on a 2.3 AVD:

```
    03-10 01:06:56.500      407-407/com.ak.ak0 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ak.ak0/com.ak.ak0.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class GridLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class GridLayout
        at ................
```

Thing is, unless I'm not understanding the gradle file correctly, I'm already using the android support libraries for compatibility:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.0.1"

}

signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("//")
        storePassword "//"
        keyAlias "//"
        keyPassword "//"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'

        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:19.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

The dependencies part from the build.gradle file were automatically generated, so I'm expecting them to be used as well (although I do not have concrete knowledge of the functionality). So then the question is, what's actually missing that's causing the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so basically for everyone running Android Studio:
Although it adds the dependency libraries by itself, some things are not added automatically.
The following needs to be added at the beginning of the XML file including the GridLayout:

```
xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Apart from this, all **GridLayout** tags from the XML file must be replaced with **android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout**

If, like me, you found out afterwards that Space also needs modifications for compatibility, the **Space** tags need to be replaced with **android.support.v7.widget.Space**